# Merge cells using cells() function

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I need to merge a range of cells vertically. There is an in-built option in excel [Merge-Across], but this merges the columns(horizontally) in a range. I need the opposite, I need to merge the rows(vertically).

I have somewhat arrived to the middle of a code. I am stuck at a place now. I need to use the merge function with the cells function. I have written a for loop to merge the rows (vertically). There are like 18 columns to be merged.

If it is by cells() it can be done easily.

The code which is available now is : Range("A1:C1").Merge

I do not know how to increment the columns in a forloop.

If any one solve this, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to merge? You could make a range variable on a single row, and use the for each loop on that to increment the columns. Or just use a Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Merge type of thing if you want cells. Although, that, just as your range, is horizontally.

Comment: Expand the cell with resize eg for col 1 rows 1 to 10 `Cells(1, 1).Resize(10).Merge`

Comment: So, what do you like merging, besides "A1:C1"? "D1:F1", "G1:I1" and so on? Or some vertical ranges of each 18 columns?

Comment: I am trying to merge F4:F30 ; G4:G30 and so on

Comment: CDP1802, i tried your way. But is there a way to use a variable for resize instead of a constant?

Comment: Christopher Weber, thanks for your answer. I think I could maybe modify this for my needs.

Comment: Of course r = row no, c=column no, n = number of rows to merge `Cells(r, c).Resize(n).Merge` or ` `Cells(r, c).Resize(1,n).Merge` to merge horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge cells columnvise vertically like this

```
Dim c As Integer

For c = 6 To 9   'columns F .. I
    Range(Cells(7, c), Cells(10, c)).Merge
Next c
```

Result: F7..F10 are merged, G7..G10, H7..H10 and I7..I10 likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Then, try the next code, please:

```
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 6 To 24
    cells(4, i).Resize(27).merge
  Next i
```